# What does beforefieldinit flag do?

Tags: .net, cil

What does beforefieldinit flag do?
When I look into the IL of my class I see this flag but I don't know what this flag is actually doing?

Answer (score 147, accepted):

See [my article](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Beforefieldinit.aspx) on this very issue.

Basically, `beforefieldinit` means "the type can be initialized at any point before any static fields are referenced." *In theory* that means it can be *very lazily* initialized - if you call a static method which doesn't touch any fields, the JIT doesn't need to initialize the type.

*In practice* it means that the class is initialized *earlier* than it would be otherwise - it's okay for it to be initialized at the start of the first method which *might* use it. Compare this with types which *don't* have `beforefieldinit` applied to them, where the type initialization has to occur immediately before the first *actual* use.

So, suppose we have:

```
public static void DoSomething(bool which)
{
    if (which)
    {
        FirstType.Foo();
    }
    else
    {
        SecondType.Bar();
    }
}
```

If both types have `beforefieldinit` applied to them (which in C# they do by default unless the type has a static constructor) then they'll *both* be initialized at the start of the `DoSomething` method (usually - it's not guaranteed). If they don't have `beforefieldinit` then only *one* of them will be initialized, based on the flag.

This is why it's common to use a static constructor (even an empty one!) when [implementing the singleton pattern](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx).

Comment: _"the type can be initialized at any point before any fields are referenced."_ is it also true for running static methods ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir, the CLI spec says that if the BeforeFieldInit is applied then "the type's initializer method is executed at, or sometime before, first access to any static field defined for that type". If that attribute is missed(static .ctor) then "first access to any static or instance field of that type, or first invocation of any static, instance or virtual method of that type". So it's not true for BeforeFieldInit applied unless the static method references another static field.

Comment: I discovered that there is a performance penalty for using static constructors (i.e. classes that do not have the beforefieldinit flag). If you call static members of a certain class frequently, it seems that the runtime has to do an extra check before each call, to test whether the type has been initialized yet; beforefieldinit avoids these checks. A couple of benchmarks were about 50% faster with beforefieldinit: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/87991/Dynamic-interfaces-in-any-NET-language

Comment: I still don't understand.  I arrived here from https://csharpindepth.com/articles/singleton.  In the fourth example of creating an instance of a Singleton, the comments in the code are     // Explicit static constructor to tell C# compiler
    // not to mark type as beforefieldinit

But doesn't a singleton ALWAYS make only one of itself?  What is gained by use of checking beforefieldinit flag?  Seems superfluous but I'm not the most intricately educated C# developer.  I do get that applying the flag makes certain of one ... isn't this overkill?

Comment: @user1585204: It's not about whether it "makes only one of itself" - it's about changing the potential timing. See https://csharpindepth.com/articles/BeforeFieldInit for more details about what BeforeFieldInit does. Without the static constructor, the singleton might be initialized even if you never actually go down a code path that uses it.

Answer (score 7):

Looks like it is going to change in 4.6

https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/1193

Comment: Awesome, so does this mean it'll wait until the very last moment to initialize the field (regardless of whether it has `beforefieldinit` or not)?

Comment: Before the first use all the accesses will be prefixed with initialization check. After that, when other methods are jitted, the generated code will  access the field directly. If it is of a primitive type then it can even be used as a JIT time constant.

Comment: Jon's detailed analysis on changes to type initialization starting .Net 4.0 [here](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/01/26/type-initialization-changes-in-net-4-0/).

Answer (score 2):

Quote from “[CA1810: Initialize reference type static fields inline (code analysis) - .NET | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca1810)” with emphasis mine and TL;DR at the bottom:

> When a type declares an explicit static constructor, the just-in-time (JIT) compiler adds a check to each static method and instance constructor of the type to make sure that the static constructor was previously called. Static initialization is triggered when any static member is accessed or when an instance of the type is created. However, static initialization is not triggered if you declare a variable of the type but do not use it, which can be important if the initialization changes global state.
>
> **When all static data is initialized inline and an explicit static constructor is not declared, Microsoft intermediate language (MSIL) compilers add the `beforefieldinit` flag and an implicit static constructor, which initializes the static data, to the MSIL type definition.**
>
> When the JIT compiler encounters the `beforefieldinit` flag, most of the time the static constructor checks are not added. Static initialization is guaranteed to occur at some time before any static fields are accessed but not before a static method or instance constructor is invoked. Note that static initialization can occur at any time after a variable of the type is declared.
>
> Static constructor checks can decrease performance. Often a static constructor is used only to initialize static fields, in which case you must only make sure that static initialization occurs before the first access of a static field. The `beforefieldinit` behavior is appropriate for these and most other types. It is only inappropriate when static initialization affects global state and one of the following is true:
>
> - The effect on global state is expensive and is not required if the type is not used.
> - The global state effects can be accessed without accessing any static fields of the type.

**TL;DR:** `beforefieldinit` flag helps avoid static constructor checks, which helps in performance (since the checks can affect performance). It does this by telling the JIT to run static constructors before the actual static field usage.

Answer (score 0):

If marked BeforeFieldInit then the type's initializer method is executed at, or sometime before, first access to any static field defined for that type.

If not marked BeforeFieldInit then that type's initializer method is executed at
first access to any static or instance field of that type, or
first invocation of any static, instance or virtual method of that type.