# Is static variable initialization order specified in SystemVerilog for variables in different packages?

Tags: system-verilog

I'm trying to find out whether static variable initialization order is specified in SystemVerilog. Starting from *6.8 Variable declarations* I didn't find anything:

> Setting the initial value of a static variable as part of the variable declaration (including static class
> members) shall occur before any initial or always procedures are started (also see 6.21 and 10.5 on variable
> initialization with static and automatic lifetimes).

---

Let's assume I have the following packages with static variables:

```
package p1;
  int v1 = 1;
endpackage

package p2;
  int v2 = 2;
endpackage
```

Is the order of initialization between these two variables defined in any way? (I'm guessing it isn't.)

What if `p2` imports `p1`:

```
package p1;
  int v1 = 1;
endpackage

package p2;
  import p1::*;

  int v2 = 2;
endpackage
```

Does this force the static initialization of `v1`? It would make sense that it would, but is this documented?

---

I'm not trying to write code that relies on initialization order. I have seen issues with code that indirectly assumes a certain initialization order. I would like to know whether the standard mandates anything or not.

Comment: For reference, it seems that C# specifies initialization order depending on when scopes are referenced: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11392744/1334062

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unspecified. In Verilog-2001, variable initializations were equivalent to `initial` process where the ordering is explicitly indeterminate.

```
integer I = 3;

// Verilog-2001 definition
integer I;
initial I = 3;
```

SystemVerilog added the paragraph you quoted which effectively puts static variable ordering in distinct event region before the active region. But now it is less obvious that the relative initialization ordering is still indeterminate.

Note that with parameterized classes and modules, it would be difficult to guarantee anything but local source ordering.