# Strange behavior then expected and performance issues of the beforefieldinit flag

Tags: c#, clr, lazy-initialization

I tried understanding the **beforefieldinit** flag.
I wrote two simple classes

```
class Foo
{
    public static object o;
    static Foo()
    {
        o = new object();
    }
}

class Bar
{
    public static object o = new object();
}
```

Then in the Main I used both classes and set a breakpoint to the **first** line of the Main method - before any code called.
In the Watch window I have checked and saw that

1. Foo.o is null
2. Bar.o is not null

this is somewhat strange since I thought the purpose of the flag was to be lazy - to prefer not initialize an object until actually needed.
This was also written about [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610818/what-does-beforefieldinit-flag-do)

What is the reason for this behavior and does it affect performance ?

I then wanted to check performance, so I wrote the following code in my Main:

```
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();

for (int i = 0; i < 2000000000; i++)
{
    object foosObject = Foo.o;
    if (foosObject == null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("");
    }
}

sw.Stop();
Console.WriteLine("With Static Ctor: " + sw.Elapsed);
sw.Reset();

sw.Start();

for (int i = 0; i < 2000000000; i++)
{
    object barsObject = Bar.o;
    if (barsObject == null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("");
    }
}

sw.Stop();
Console.WriteLine("Without Static Ctor: " + sw.Elapsed);
sw.Reset();
```

And the output was

> With Static Ctor: 00:00:06.0167153
>
> Without Static Ctor: 00:00:04.2441007

So that's a **50%** difference in performance. Why does the first loop run slower ? I have looked at the IL with ILDASM and I didn't see any difference

Comment: Looks normal. The JIT executes the cctor in Bar at the time Bar is referenced when compiling Main so that it can assume that Bar is initialized. There's a change request, btw, to make this behavior more controllable: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/4448

Comment: @HansPassant - Why does observing Foo.o didn't invoke it's static constructor while observing Bar.o did initialize it ?